# Jenkins super slow

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have Jenkins server whose GUI is super slow whenever I refresh it takes at least a few mins to respond. I am copying the entire Jenkins folder from one server to another and starting the Jenkins

Couple of scenarios I have tested 
1. setting up Jenkins on high-performance server ie 64GB Ram 16Vcpus and 300GB of Harddrive
2. Increasing the Java Memory arguments of the server to min and max to 16GB and made sure it is using the G1GC Algorithm

Expecting Jenkins to be as fast as possible

Comment: Do you find anything of interest in the log? If you have a lot of folders you can disable their health metrics in the meantime to increase responsiveness.

Comment: Do you regularly discard old builds? I've found that when my jobs directory gets too large, I start seeing some flakey behavior.  Mine recently had about 4 million files in it, that was too much. I set my jobs to discard after 25 runs, or 30 days. Seems to have made a difference. And there's nothing useful in the log when this happens.